# regular expression in xml

Tags: regex, eclipse

The Eclipse software has a functionality to search for regular expressions.
I'd like to search for all `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>` strings whose xml parent node is not `<parent>`.

What would be the easiest way to do that ?

Comment: So you want to find that string only within a `Z` tag, right (if it's not a "parent" tag)?

Comment: I'm not sure that the way you put it is equivalent to mine.
I can have different nested Z tags, for example `<A><B><version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version></B></A>`. What I don't want is `<A><project><version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version></project></A>`

Comment: Let me put this another way: all xml nodes have a parent (except for the root). In particular, the node <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> has a parent. I don't want this parent to be <parent>, that's all (regardless of other childs that the node 'parent' might have, or brothers, or parents, or whatever)

Comment: OK, now I'm confused. So it's not `<Z attribute="parent">bam</Z>` but `<foo>bar</foo>baz<parent>bam<parent>`, and you want to match `bar` and `baz` but not `bam`?

Comment: Yes, your second example is correct, although I only want to match bar and baz if bar or baz is equal to <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>.

Comment: OK, so in essence you could say that you want to match `<version...` if the next `<parent>` tag isn't a closing `</parent>` tag, right? This assumes that `<parent>` tags can't be nested.

Comment: Sorry about my X,Y,Z, they were not meant to confuse you. They are not part of my question, they are just strings such as 'foo' or 'bar' and you can replace them by whatever you want. My second comment (the one that starts with "let me put this another way") is perhaps easier to understand. Perhaps the only confusing part left is that the parent of the string I'm looking for is unfortunately called "parent".

Comment: Yes you're right, that's a way to put it. parent tags can't indeed be nested, although there could be more than one parent tag in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Complete rewrite.

As long as `<parent>` tags can't be nested, this is possible, but only then (and all the usual caveats about not trying to match XML with regexes apply. As soon as you have comments or CDATA sections in your XML, all bets are off).

```
(?s)<version>0\.0\.1-SNAPSHOT</version>(?!(?:(?!</?parent>).)*</parent>)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)              # Turn on singleline matching mode
<version>0\.0\.1-SNAPSHOT</version> # Match this string
(?!               # but only do this if it's impossible to match this regex here:
 (?:              # Try to match...
  (?!</?parent)   #  (as long as there is no <parent> or </parent> tag ahead)
  .               #  any character
 )*               # any number of times
 </parent>        # Then match </parent>
)                 # End of lookahead
```

Comment: This still catches   
<parent>
  <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
  <groupId>groupID</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

Comment: I don't see this: http://regex101.com/r/gZ2jW4. But I forgot to paste the `(?s)` modifier in the one-liner regex. Please try again.